# Why is a char[] array '\0' terminated by std::cin?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int main() {
    char suffix[25];
    cout<<"Enter some suffix: ";
    cin >> suffix;
    cout << endl <<suffix;
}
```

See the **[full sample](http://ideone.com/RSB10r)**

input:

```
dog
```

output:

```
dog
```

expected output:

```
dog#*(!&!XΓ◘♪<♣@!(!)XΓ◘♪<♣☺XΓ◘♪<♣
```

What is the fundamental thing I'm missing about pointers (if this does in fact have to do with pointers) and their ability to retain exactly what was given? Even a strlen(suffix) yields 3, when I expect it to be 25. Printing suffix[6], for example, prints nothing at all, not even a space

Comment: Probably null-terminated.

Comment: Of course `strlen(suffix)` will yield three, you entered a three character string. `suffix[3]` will be a null character, it won't print out the uninitialized elements.

Comment: The "fundamental thing you're missing" is that C++ cout and cin transparently treat `char[]` as a C string!  No mystery.  "suffx[]" holds `{'d', 'o', 'g', '\0', ...}`.

Comment: You seem to expect `operator>>(char[])` not to NUL-terminate its input.  1. The documentation says that it will.  2. Think about the implications if it didn't: This would *force you to zero out the entire array each time*.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Remember, there are no stupid questions.

Comment: @Thilo Well, there are questions not fitting the actual requirements of SO. [Read more about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), if you're in doubt, or even [ask on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about this particular question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: If the question is off-topic, it should be closed or migrated. Not downvoted. And why is this off-topic? It tries to establish an understanding how pointers, arrays, null-bytes are used to implement strings in C++. OP also went the extra mile to include a minimal example to demonstrate his question.

Comment: @Thilo 1st of all the OP missed to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may bang the question in shape, if you're willing to do so, and think it's really worth it (being helpful for future researchers).

Comment: How are the four lines of code not a MCVE ? Seeing that it got six upvoted answers (counting comments), it did not stop some people from understanding the problem.

Comment: @Thilo Well, I see now in which way you're right. Still the question is pretty poor (let's say the title alone).

Answer (score 3):

When you read or write a `char*` with `cin` and `cout`, it treats it as a C-style string. `cin` adds a null terminator at the end of the line, and `cout` only writes until it gets to the null terminator. `strlen()` counts characters until the null terminator.

`suffix[6]` will contain whatever random garbage happened to be in that byte when the array was allocated. If you're not seeing anything with `cout << suffix[6]`, it's because the random garbage happened to be a non-printing character.

Comment: ... and `strlen` also advances until it finds a null terminator.

Answer (score 2):

`cin` installs a null after "dog"; as a result `cout` stops showing characters after "dog". This is by c++ method for recognizing end of character strings.

Nothing pointer-ish here

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` operator with a `char*` right operand reads from the stream and writes a C-style string to the specified array. (The `char*` value is the result of the implicit conversion of the array expression `suffix`.)

It stores a terminating null character `'\0'` into the array to mark the end of the string. The contents of the array after the `'\0'` are left alone.

`strlen` and `cout << suffix` both look for this terminator to determine how long the string is.

As for `suffix[6]`, that's a valid element of the array, but it's beyond the end of the string. Its contents are garbage. It's fairly likely, though by no means certain, that it contains a null character; printing it will probably have no visible effect. If you convert it to an `int`, you can see the actual value.